# Remove background image if browser height is larger than 1080px

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the image if the browser height is larger than 1080 pixels.  For example android devices would have more than 1080 when the page loads and my image is loaded and it goes down to about 2/3 of the page and the rest of it is blank.  I would rather it be gone entirely.  How can I get rid of it.  Here is how I am setting it:

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("../images/myimage.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center top;
  background-position:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

what I tried

```
@media screen and (min-height: 1080px) {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
@media device and (orientation: portrait) and (min-height: 1080px) {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at other questions here? (Answer: media queries, google it)

Comment: background-image: none;

Answer (score 2):

Try a media query!

```
/* standard*/
@media screen and (min-height: 1080px) {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
/* orientation */
@media device and (orientation: portrait) and (min-height: 1080px) {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't that depend on the width, not height?

Comment: Ah, whoops! Let's try that again.

Comment: Just switch to height / portrait.

Comment: Would we then use min-height or max-height?

Comment: I would say `min-height`. This will set a style for that pixel height and anything above it, until your next media query break point. :)

Comment: that did not work.  If you can load southpawgaming.com on your cellphone and look on the right.  You will see the background image, hard to see but its there.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a media query here, but you want to focus on max-height (not width... which is what media queries typically focus on, eg, http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/height-based-media-queries.php)

```
@media screen and ( min-height: 1080px ){
         body { background-image: none; }
    }
```

You should probably spend a bit of time learning about mobile responsive design in general, specifically because the media queries can come in handy with problems like yours. This is a very good place to start reading about them: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/

Also note that certain JS plugins (eg Backstretch for example) stretch your image to whatever the background size happens to be... that might be another thing to look into, if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer not to stretch the image as it will look fairly bad.

Comment: Fair enough. Use a media query. You might want to use !important on this media query... it just kind of depends on how good your CSS is :-)

Comment: One thing you should probably be aware of.... media queries are supported by modern browsers, but not older ones... so if you have a lot of folks using old browsers with screen res's higher than 1080, you might have a problem... in which cases something like Modernizr might come in handy... but that's not an especially likely scenario here. Just something to be aware of that can be a problem in some cases (likely not this one)

Answer (score -1):

Give the element containing the background image an id attribute then use that id attribute to assign the style to the background using an if statement with JavaScript.

```
            <script>

            var element = document.getElementById("elementHoldingTheBackground");

            if (1080 < window.innerHeight ) { // returns a number
                element.style.display="none"; // hides the element with CSS
            }

            </script>
```

That's the most simple way from the top of my head but I'm sure there are better ways to do it!

I'm also no expert. Please don't cook me over this. I'm only 18. I'm new to this!

Please tell me what you think.

Comment: I would prefer not to use javascript.

Comment: What about PHP? Scripting would be the best way to deal with the situation but the @media query may work. I don't have experience with CSS queries.